# Create multiple JSON objects using PHP associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON response of sports players. I have this script which queries the MySQL database and produces an associative array.

```
$meta = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // $meta[] = $res;
    $meta[] = array(
        'guid' => $res['guid'],
        'name' => $res['name'],
        'dob' => $res['date_of_birth'],
        'birthplace' => $res['birthplace'],
        'height' => $res['height'],
        'weight' => $res['weight'],
        'position' => $res['position'],
        'honours' => $res['honours']
    );
}

$meta = json_encode(array('players' => $meta), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $meta
```

I want to able to return a "player" JSON object for each player in the database but I'm unsure how to create that structure.

Here is my current response:

```
{
"players": [
    {
        "guid": "1",
        "name": "Matias Aguero",
        "dob": "1981-02-13",
        "birthplace": "San Nicolas, Argentina",
        "height": "1.83m (6' 0\")",
        "weight": "109kg (17st 2lb)",
        "position": "Prop",
        "honours": "40 caps"
    },
    {
        "guid": "2",
        "name": "George Catchpole",
        "dob": "1994-02-22",
        "birthplace": "Norwich, England",
        "height": "1.85em (6ft 1\")",
        "weight": "104kg (16st 5lb)",
        "position": "Centre",
        "honours": ""
    },
    {
        "guid": "3",
        "name": "Logovi'i Mulipola",
        "dob": "1987-03-11",
        "birthplace": "Manono, W Samoa",
        "height": "1.93 (6' 4\")",
        "weight": "130kg (20st 6lb)",
        "position": "Prop",
        "honours": "Samoa (17 caps)"
    }
  ]
}
```

My ideal architecture would be

```
"players" : [ "player" { "data" } ] // APOLOGIES FOR THE SHORTHAND
```

Comment: Try with `$meta['player'][] = array(..)`

Comment: you dont have to do anything ! echo json_encode($meta); inside meta every object is a player . still you want again within player then $players[] = array('player'=>$meta); then echo json_encode($players); will give desired result

Comment: @SumeetDarade Yeah, you understand. They are objects already, I just want to call each one "player" before the data. Your suggestion prints out `players [ player->all objects ]`

I want `players [player1 : {data1} player2 : {data2} ]` and so on! Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yeah got it ! actually got it when i saw rjhdby's answer. his answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$meta = array();
while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    // $meta[] = $res;
    $meta[$res['name']] = array(
        'guid' => $res['guid'],
//        'name' => $res['name'],
        'dob' => $res['date_of_birth'],
        'birthplace' => $res['birthplace'],
        'height' => $res['height'],
        'weight' => $res['weight'],
        'position' => $res['position'],
        'honours' => $res['honours']
    );
}

$meta = json_encode(array('players' => $meta), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $meta
```

If I undesrstand question